# How do you declare variables x1, x2,...,x10 using a loop function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, logic, javascript-objects

I am trying to run the following code in JavaScript to accomplish the following task: declare a series of variables that essentially have the same name but are only different in their suffix, which is an integer, e.g. x1,x2,x3... and so on.

I am new to JavaScript (in fact, I'm entirely new to the coding world). The following code is what I thought made logical sense but it doesn't want to execute the way I want it to.

```js
for (i = 1; i<11; i++) {
  var x+i = 'variable'+i;
  }
```

There's something else I wish to do...

Say, for example, I made a construct such as the following and then proceeded to create customised objects (student1, student2, student3). My end goal is to print out, sequentially, the student's name and a comment on their grade. Instead of having to type out the function that would print this out for each student I would like to write a loop that would make this process more efficient. However, trying to do this has proven a bit difficult. Here is the code:

```js
var grade = function(grade) {
  switch (grade) {
      case "A": " could not do any better. Well done";
      break;
      case "C": " had average performance. There's room to improve.";
      break;
      case "F": ", an unfortunate result. Will have to try again next year.";
      break;
      default: ".";
      break;
      }
  };

function Student(name, sgrade) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grade = sgrade;
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(this.name+grade(this.grade));
  };
 }

var student1 = new Student("Candice R.", "A");
var student2 = new Student("Robert K.", "C");
var student3 = new Student("Steven M.", "F");

for (i = 1; i<4; i++) {
  student+i.print();
  }

/* student[i].print() also doesn't work */
```

Can someone tell me what logic of JavaScript I am not fully understanding that does not allow the above to execute, and is there another way?

Comment: Usually, you don't.  You use an array for storing sequences of data.

Comment: Can you give me an example of code that you would use to do what I am trying to do? I have two examples above, would you mind showing me how you would approach both? You just have to write out the code.

Comment: It's really no more difficult than understanding how an Array works in Javascript.  If you don't know that yet, then that's your next learning in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 for your input. I appreciate your constructive help.

Answer (score 4):

As jfriend00 says, the piece of javascript that you're looking for is arrays.

Whenever you find yourself adding numbers to variable names, that should indicate that you could put them in an array.

So you could replace this:

```
var student1 = new Student("Candice R.", "A");
var student2 = new Student("Robert K.", "C");
var student3 = new Student("Steven M.", "F");
```

with this:

```
var students = [];
students.push(new Student("Candice R.", "A"));
students.push(new Student("Robert K.", "C"));
students.push(new Student("Steven M.", "F"));
```

Now all three of those students are stored together in the `students` array. The first student is accessed at `students[0]`, and your for loop should be able to iterate over them easily.

There are perhaps better ways to define this array of students, but this is a pretty close translation of your existing code.

Comment: Thanks @crgk. I believe this is the most efficient way of writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use an array to store your variables and use numeric indices to access them like this:

```
var students = []; // create an array and add student objects to it
students[0] = new Student("Candice R.", "A");
students[1] = new Student("Robert K.", "C");
students[2] = new Student("Steven M.", "F");

for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  students[i].print();
}
```

if you really wanted to use the names "student1", "student2", "student3", you could do something like:

```
var students = {}; // create an empty object and add students as properties
students["student1"] = new Student("Candice R.", "A");
students["student2"] = new Student("Robert K.", "C");
students["student3"] = new Student("Steven M.", "F");

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  students["student" + i].print();
}
```

To answer the question of creating such variables in a loop:

```
var x = {};
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  x['x' + i] = 'variable' + i;
}
```

Comment: The object is an interesting approach. I like it - might be more intuitive for some people.

Comment: I learned that trick while doing exactly what OP wants years ago, except at the time I was using the `window` object like @meteorite suggested. But I don't like polluting the global scope so I changed it up a bit for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another name for variable is "identifier."  Every programming language one can think of restricts names to a specific combination of characters.  For:
   var x+i;

The interpreter sees this and the declaration is an invalid set of characters for an identifier in JavaScript...because it has + operator.  Common restriction is not starting a variable name with a number.  Restricting to $/_/[A-Z] for the first character and then a mix of numbers...

What you are looking for is to use a data structure such as an array or a hash table.

```
var x ={};
var array = []; 

for (i = 1; i<11; i++) {
    //Add a new object property called x1...x2... to the variable x.
   x["x" + i] = 'variable'+i;
   //Add a new string to the Array
   array.push('variable' + i);
}

//Iterate through the properties of the x object you just created
for(var k in x)
{
  //retrieve the item by using x["x1"]
   console.log(x[k]);
}

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
   //Retrieve array item by index (starts with zero)
      console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this and it should be ok:

```
for (i = 1; i<4; i++) {
  window['student'+i].print();
  }
```

Comment: Much better to just use your own array rather than create lots of globals.

Comment: The question is about how those variables can be accessed.

Comment: Good answers suggest better techniques to use rather than just answer a literal question that's asking how to do a poor practice.

Comment: It depends I think. In this case the author of the question is curious about why his/her technique is not working. Therefore, the answer must address this issue first. Then ,a better/good practice can be suggested.

Comment: Nothing wrong with explaining why `var x+i = 'variable'+i;` does not work (illegal Javascript syntax), but you don't do that.  Instead, you suggest a correct syntax way to implement the wrong solution.  I didn't downvote you myself, but I thought I should explain that stack overflow is essentially a competition for the "best answer" and best answers often need to do more than literally answer what was asked.  They need to understand the actual problem and offer the best solution to that problem.